# Calculate the limit of the sequence by applying the limit laws?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

[image]

I'm not sure how to approach this problem since its a bit different to the usual questions about calculating limits .

Comment: *Hint*: Start by showing that if $L\in \mathbb{R}$ is the limit, the fact that $\sqrt{1+x}$ is continuous implies that $L=\sqrt{1+L}$...

Comment: Note that what @G.Sassatelli has suggested will only tell you what the limit must be if it exists but not that the sequence converges to a limit.

Comment: Of course, the point highlighted by @DanRobertson is the second crucial thing to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you can show by induction that $\{x_n\}$ is monotonically increasing and bounded.  This implies that the sequence converges to say $L$.

Now,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n}$$

implies

$$L=\sqrt{1+L}.$$